# Как запустить метод из одного скрипта в другом?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно запустить метод `StartMotion` из скрипта `ClickObj` в скрипте `Game`.
Unity показывает ошибку

> The name `StartMotion` does not exist in the current context

и я не могу понять, как её исправить.

---

Вот скрипты

```cs
public class ClickObj : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool move;
    private Vector2 randomVector;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!move) return;
        transform.Translate(randomVector * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    public void StartMotion(int cashIncrease)
    {
        GetComponent<Text>().text = "+" + cashIncrease;
        randomVector = new Vector2(1, Random.Range(0,10));
        move = true;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Game: MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject clickParent, clickTextPrefab;
    public ClickObj[] clickTextPool = new ClickObj[30];

    private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < clickTextPool.Length; i++)
        {
            clickTextPool[i] = Instantiate(clickTextPrefab, 
            clickParent.transform).GetComponent<ClickObj>();  
        }
    }

    public void Click ()
    {
        clickTextPool[0] = StartMotion(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы вообще пытались решить эту проблему самостоятельно? Основы языка изучить и всякое такое? :)

Comment: нет) пришлось использовать C#, вот и мучаюсь

Comment: Ну тогда мучайтесь дальше, раз вы даже не хотите и пальцем пошевелить, чтобы проблему решить ;)

Comment: хорошо, найду ответ сам, это правильно, и я это прекрасно понимаю и знаю, просто есть куча других задач и не так уж много времени, поэтому подумал, что будет проще спросить у знатоков, не подскажите хорошие источники?

Comment: Любые книги/курсы/видео для начинающих, вы не понимаете, как устроено ооп в C#, в этом и проблема.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Помочь ему?)

Comment: @Alt_F4 Дело ваше, я принципиально не помогаю, потому что человек не захотел даже основы языка изучить :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я попробовал объяснить "максимально коротко" чтобы больше такие вопросы не задавали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Объяснение

Все скрипты в котором вы пишите код `class`-ы.

[image]

Что представляет из себя `class`. Можно сказать `class` это группа разных переменных. Например представим что делаем `class` Человек. Каким мы должны его сделать.
Основные данные человека -

- Имя
- Возраст
- Пол
- Год рождения

и. т. д.

Теперь делаем `class` -

```cs
class Human
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public string sex; //Это не смешно, это переводится как пол
    public int birthday;
}
```

Теперь создаём человека -

```cs
new Human Arman;
//создаём новый Человек Арман | Арман это имя class-а
```

Мы теперь должны дать ему необходимые данные

```cs
Arman.name = "Arman"; //имя Армана равно Арман
Arman.age = 17; // возраст Армана равно 17
Arman.sex = "male" // пол Армана равно мужской
Arman.birthday = 2002; // год рождения Армана равно 2002
```

Теперь чтобы например спросить человека "Сколько тебе лет?" сначала должны обратится к нему -

```cs
Debug.Log(Arman.age);
//Покажи мне Арман.возраст (то есть возраст Армана)
```

---

## Ошибки

У меня много вопросов насчёт того что вы писали.

- Сначала вот тут

[image]

Зачем тут использовать `return`?

- А тут вообще не понятно

[image]

То что вы написали в функции `Click` вообще шедевр.
Вы `class`-у даёте значение функции которое не возвращает значение.

---

## Решение

```cs
public class ClickObj : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool move;
    private Vector2 randomVector;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (move)
        {
            gameObject.transform.Translate(randomVector * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    public void StartMotion(int cashIncrease)
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = "+" + cashIncrease;
        randomVector = new Vector2(1, Random.Range(0,10));
        move = true;
    }
}
```

```cs
public GameObject clickParent, clickTextPrefab;
public ClickObj[] clickTextPool = new ClickObj[30];

private void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < clickTextPool.Length; i++)
    {
        clickTextPool[i]  = Instantiate(clickTextPrefab, clickParent.transform).GetComponent<ClickObj>();        
    }
}

//Используйте функции более масштабно чтобы не писать их 40 раз.
public void Click (int id, float value)
{        
    clickTextPool[id].StartMotion(value);
}
```